# Passing true / false to slideToggle()

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, I know that we can pass `true` or `false` value to the function to `toggle` visibility of an element. I can't get `slideToggle` to do the same thing. Any help please?

For example, instead of:

```
if (true)
    $('something').slideDown();
else
    $('something').slideUp();
```

I would really like to do something similar to:

```
$('something').toggle(myBoolValue);
```

But I want to do it with *`slideToggle`*.

Look at [my example of jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fy3vy/) to know what I am trying to do.

Is that possible?

Comment: What's wrong with your if statment? (other than no curly braces)

Comment: @jondavidjohn, having no curly braces is not wrong! and with my statement, I am just curious if I have any smarter way of doing things

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`slideToggle` optionally takes 2 parameters `duration` and a `callback` so passing true/false to show/hide will not work. You might have to write your own plugin which will implement this logic. Something like this

```
$.fn.mySllideToggle = function(show){
   if(show){
      $(this).slideDown();
   }
   else{
      $(this).slideUp();
   }
}
```

Comment: I did think of this, but I wasn't willing to believe that there wasn't something simpler.. oh well

Comment: I will accept this answer when the time limit gets over.. since it is most logical, explaining the two optional parameters.. thanks

Comment: Thanks @LocustHorde glad it helped you.

Comment: This answer does not follow normal jQuery method conventions. `this` is already a `jQuery` type, no need to create new ones, and it doesn't chain.

Answer (score 5):

It is simple like this:

```
$.fn.slideToggleBool = function(bool, options) {
  return bool? $(this).slideDown(options) : $(this).slideUp(options);
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: The extra `$(…)` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

It can be shimmed in like so:

```js
;(function($) {
    var slideToggleOrig = $.fn.slideToggle;
    $.fn.slideToggle = function(display) {
        var fn,
            args = arguments;
        if ('boolean' != typeof display) {
            fn = slideToggleOrig;
        }
        else {
            if (display) {
                fn = this.slideDown;
            }
            else {
                fn = this.slideUp;
            }
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1);// hide the extra arg from official functions
        }
        return fn.apply(this, args);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This works by detecting if the first argument to `slideToggle` is a boolean (not just truthy/falsy) and, if so, substituting the up and down functions which have compatible signatures. This means you can use any existing signature, but add an extra argument at the start. It also chains correctly without modifying the stack or creating a new object.

Answer (score -6):

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

```
$('something').slideToggle('slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WLp9z/1/

Comment: Hi, the initial values vary, so I can actually start with div invisible OR checkbox unchecked.. so in either case, checking them would be doign quite the opposite!